# mysqlclient sporadically crashes making TLS connections

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) to connect from one server to another, which is running MariaDB 10.0.27.

Connections that don't use TLS work without any problem. Most connections that do use TLS work without any problem. However, sometimes the Python script crashes, like:

`` *** Error in `python': double free or corruption (fasttop): 
0x0000000000eccea0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x71ff5)[0x7f23b22f7ff5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77946)[0x7f23b22fd946]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7812e)[0x7f23b22fe12e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2(CRYPTO_free+0x1d)[0x7f23b057fddd]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2(OBJ_NAME_add+0x91)[0x7f23b0582951]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2(EVP_add_cipher+0x25)[0x7f23b0641a65]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2(SSL_library_init+0x11)[0x7f23b09b86b1]
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18(+0x58fe4)[0x7f23ad81cfe4]
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18(+0x591a4)[0x7f23ad81d1a4]
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18(+0x2ab9b)[0x7f23ad7eeb9b]
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18(+0x2afed)[0x7f23ad7eefed]
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18(+0x28066)[0x7f23ad7ec066]
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18(+0x2b2e3)[0x7f23ad7ef2e3]
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18(mysql_real_connect+0xba2)[0x7f23ad7f1542]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so(+0x5c82)[0x7f23add39c82]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0xb8e2c)[0x7f23b3004e2c]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f23b2fa05c3]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x375e)[0x7f23b305309e]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x81c)[0x7f23b30592cc]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0x855ed)[0x7f23b2fd15ed]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f23b2fa05c3]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0x6588c)[0x7f23b2fb188c]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f23b2fa05c3]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0xbff2d)[0x7f23b300bf2d]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0xbe92f)[0x7f23b300a92f]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f23b2fa05c3]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x375e)[0x7f23b305309e]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x81c)[0x7f23b30592cc]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5cf0)[0x7f23b3055630]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x81c)[0x7f23b30592cc]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0x855ed)[0x7f23b2fd15ed]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f23b2fa05c3]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x375e)[0x7f23b305309e]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x81c)[0x7f23b30592cc]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0x855ed)[0x7f23b2fd15ed]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f23b2fa05c3]
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x375e)[0x7f23b305309e]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5e01)[0x7f23b3055741]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5e01)[0x7f23b3055741]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x81c)[0x7f23b30592cc]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0x8551c)[0x7f23b2fd151c]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f23b2fa05c3]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0x6588c)[0x7f23b2fb188c]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f23b2fa05c3]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x47)[0x7f23b304f347]/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.1(+0x14aa22)[0x7f23b3096a22]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7454)[0x7f23b2d36454]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f23b236eecd] ``

(And then there's a memory map, and the word "aborted").

I haven't been able to find any way to reliably reproduce this, and haven't been able to identify anything that happens on the originating server or the MariaDB server at the time the problem happens that could explain it.

The server's TLS settings are:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like "%ssl%";
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                          
| Variable_name | Value                                                 |                                                                                                                                                          
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                          
| have_openssl  | YES                                                   |                                                                                                                                                          
| have_ssl      | YES                                                   |                                                                                                                                                          
| ssl_ca        | /etc/ssl/private/ca-cert.pem                          |                                                                                                                                                          
| ssl_capath    |                                                       |                                                                                                                                                          
| ssl_cert      | /etc/ssl/private/client-cert.pem                      |                                                                                                                                                          
| ssl_cipher    | CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA |                                                                                                                                                          
| ssl_crl       |                                                       |                                                                                                                                                          
| ssl_crlpath   |                                                       |                                                                                                                                                          
| ssl_key       | /etc/ssl/private/client-key.pem                       |                                                                                                                                                          
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

The Python code is passing the SSL variables with `ssl={"key": "/etc/ssl/private/client-key.pem", "cert": "/etc/ssl/private/client-cert.pem"}`. It seems unlikely the issue is with these, since the majority of the connections do work properly. The MariaDB user has `REQUIRE SSL` set, so all connections do need to be using TLS.

What's going wrong here? Or if that can't be determined, how can I further investigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an upstream problem with libmysqlclient (or libssl). The problem seems to occur when using `mysqlclient` within a threaded program with SSL connections. This does happen randomly even though the connections are localized to specific threads.

I'm not 100% sure which version are impacted, but I can confirm the issue on these versions:

`ii  libssl1.0.2:amd64               1.0.2i-1                     amd64
ii  libc6:amd64                     2.22-6                       amd64
ii  libmysqlclient18                10.0.27+maria-1~sid          amd64`

And fixed in these versions:

`ii  libssl1.0.2:amd64               1.0.2j-1                    amd64
ii  libc6:amd64                     2.24-5                      amd64
ii  libmariadbclient18:amd64        10.0.28-1                   amd64`

See also the related [github issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/132)